# В гугл таблицах необходим сложный скрипт/макрос/sql-запрос (автоматическое формирование счета и и ряд проверок)

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, скрипт, макросы

Пожалуйста, помогите, как можно максимально просто решить данную задачу в гугл таблицах?

Есть 3 таблицы 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lhVRrWJrdL9yujUd4RhtVelQnATAgLhKxq2idvJ83Y0/edit?usp=sharing

Лист 1. Магазины
Это входные данные(логирование часов по задачам, клиентам и менеджерам). Обновляются ежемесячно.
Наименования колонок могут меняться, порядок - нет. Набор строк меняется ежемесячно.

Лист 2. Затраты по клиентам и менеджерам
Поля, выделенные красным, должны формироваться автоматически и обновляться при изменении данных (на основе Листа 1 и Листа 3)

Лист 3. Зарплаты
Поля, выделенные красным, должны пересчитываться автоматически и обновляться при изменении данных Листа 1.
Если на Листе 1 есть менеджеры, которых нет на Листе 3, то должно быть оповещение о том, что не все менеджеры внесены.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Спросите тут https://t.me/googleappsscriptrc

Comment: Спасибо! Добавила метку